# How to convert a GeoJSON Point to a pair of fields (longitude, latitude) in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying convert a GeoJSON Point field to a pair of numerics fields in the server side.

FROM:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d6bb9c0df513c70215b39f"),
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -6.12026811214226, 
            37.37425297074252
        ]
    }
}
```

TO:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d6bb9c0df513c70215b39f"),
    "longitude" : -6.12026811214226, 
    "latitude" : 37.37425297074252
}
```

In PHP, I have something like this:

```
function extractCoordinates($tak) {
    $coordinates = $tak["location"]["coordinates"];

    $tak["longitude"] = $coordinates[0];
    $tak["latitude"] = $coordinates[1];
    unset($tak["location"]);
    return $tak;
}
```

But I need do this in my MongoDB Server. Is it posible?

Comment: Do you mean via the mongo shell/client?

Comment: Actually I'm traying to get a query something like `db.taks_copy.aggregate([
    {$match: {subAdministrativeArea:"Sevilla"}},
    {$group: {_id: "$locality", total: {$sum: 1}, longitude: {$avg: "$location.coordinates.0"}, latitude: {$avg: "$location.coordinates.1"}}}
])`. I'll translate it to a PHP MongoClient call, but for the moment I'm trying to get it working in my Robomongo client.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that on MongoDB side. The following query extract the coordinates, and after that you could create the hash with `longitude`, `latitude` keys and assign values.

```
  db.testData.aggregate({'$unwind': "$location.coordinates"},
                        {'$group':{_id: "$location.coordinates"}})
```

Result is:

```
 {
     "result" : [ 
         { 
             "_id" : 37.37425297074252
        }, 
        {
              "_id" : -6.12026811214226
        }
     ],
     "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I'm still trying others solutions. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

This aggregation will do the job.

```
db.taks_copy.aggregate([
 {
     $project:{ 
         longitude: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$location.coordinates", 0 ] },
         latitude: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$location.coordinates", -1 ] }
     }
 }     
])
```

here are the results

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9a02fa16766b7b104b0e15"),
    "lon" : 1.1948052971367,
    "lat" : 43.4337798174773
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9a02fa16766b7b104b0e16"),
    "lon" : 1.38299104246662,
    "lat" : 43.2228713859383
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9a02fa16766b7b104b0e17"),
    "lon" : 1.22600505804185,
    "lat" : 43.8914578939366
}
```

Comment: Only one question answered in SO and it saved me, thanks Laurent!!!