# Find max, min coordinate values from mongodb geojson point collection

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My use case is fairly simple: I have a collection of documents in a mongodb with geographic coordinate specified as GeoJSON Point.

I want to find the bounding box for this collection, defined as lat min, long min, lat max, long max.

The documents have the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("538ed354b83897b4418b4567"),
  "name": "example point",
  "description": "",
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      24.501885327447624,
      42.228924279974158
    ]
  },
  "status": "1",
  "type": "image"
}
```

After a lot of searching and trial and error I'm stuck how to proceed.

I found a couple of nice working approaches which work for subdocuments (arrays) with key/value pairs, but so far I haven't found anything for a plain array such as the GeoJSON coordinates pair.

With aggregation I face the problem that I'm not able to extract the X, Y coordinates from the GeoJSON point (tried using `$slice: [0,1]` and `$slice: [1,1]` but this appears not to work in a `$project` pipeline). [Unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027086/how-to-convert-a-geojson-point-to-a-pair-of-fields-longitude-latitude-in-mong) doesn't seem the right approach either.

Map/reduce looks like a lot of overkill for what would be a really basic query in a RDMS.

What would be my best approach (latest mongodb release 2.6.3)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right approach is [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) as "slice" and "positional projections" are not valid at present for either [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). As such there is really nothing new offered in MongoDB 2.6 releases that changes the approach:

But really you need are two [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages in order to get the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) from your "coordinates" array and then pass those through to [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/):

```
db.geoobj.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$location.coordinates" },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "lat": { "$first": "$location.coordinates" },
        "lon": { "$last": "$location.coordinates" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "minLat": { "$min": "$lat" },
        "minLon": { "$min": "$lon" },
        "maxLat": { "$max": "$lat" },
        "maxLon": { "$max": "$lon" }
    }}
])
```

That produces the four coordinates representing the minimal and maximal point bounds for your collection. You could get fancier and transform that into a "Polygon" representation using operators such as [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) but really that is another question.

Comment: Excellent! Just one minor thing if you copy this literally: in GeoJSON [coordinates are in (Longitude, Latitude) order](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id2), other than in conventional notations which e.q. google maps use.

Simply swapping lat and lon in grouping stage #1 does the trick.